# Get Current Active user from the Zoom iOS SDK Custom Meeting implementation

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, zoom-sdk

I have implemented the Zoom iOS SDK to work with a custom UI. Everything works just as its supposed to but I haven't been able to figure out how I can get the userID of the currently active user.

I have implemented the below delegate method which tells about the current active video user, but unfortunately it shows all the other participants in the meeting except me.

```
func onSinkMeetingActiveVideo(_ userID: UInt) {
    if let service = MobileRTC.shared().getMeetingService(), let username = service.userInfo(byID: userID)?.userName {
        print("\(#function) : \(userID) : \(username)")
    }
}
```

I need to know who is the current active user even if its me who is talking.

Comment: Can you try using onSinkMeetingActiveVideoForDeck instead of onSinkMeetingActiveVideo?

Comment: @cristallo for some reason its never called. only `onSinkMeetingActiveVideo` is called in the delegate.

Comment: Ummm I am pretty confused. Are you using the latest SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve this kind of information from meeting service MobileRTCMeetingService.

[MobileRTCMeetingService](https://zoom.github.io/zoom-sdk-ios/interface_mobile_r_t_c_meeting_service.html)

```
func getActiveUserId() -> UInt? {
    if let meetingService = MobileRTC.shared().getMeetingService() {
        return meetingService.activeUserID()
    }
    return nil
}
```

Extra note: in Zoom there is also the concept of Pinned User that overrides active user in active video cell.
Pinned user id can be retrieved in this way:

```
func getPinnedUserId() -> UInt? {
    if let meetingService = MobileRTC.shared().getMeetingService(), let userList = meetingService.getInMeetingUserList(){
        for userId in userList {
            if let userId = userId as? UInt, meetingService.isUserPinned(userId) {
                return userId
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    return nil
}
```

So in order to establish which is the user id of the video in active video cell you have to check both, giving priority to pinned user.

```
let currentVideoUserId = getPinnedUserId() ?? getActiveUserId()
```

During the meeting you will never been the active user in your own video cell because even if your are speaking, you will continue to see the other person in active video cell.

On the other side if you are interested to know who is talking then you have to retrieve the user list and check the audioStatus [MobileRTCAudioStatus].

[MobileRTCAudioStatus](https://marketplacefront.zoom.us/sdk/meeting/ios/interface_mobile_r_t_c_audio_status.html)

[MobileRTCMeetingUserInfo](https://marketplacefront.zoom.us/sdk/meeting/ios/interface_mobile_r_t_c_meeting_user_info.html)

Just pay attention that you can have more than one user speaking at the same time.

There is also another callback that can be useful if you are interested in active speaker user: it is the onSinkMeetingActiveVideoForDeck in MobileRTCVideoServiceDelegate

[MobileRTCVideoServiceDelegate](https://zoom.github.io/zoom-sdk-ios/protocol_mobile_r_t_c_video_service_delegate_01-p.html)

According to the documentation it should be fired every time that there is a new speaker. It is used by ZOOM UI for changing the yellow frame around the active speaker user.

Answer (score 0):

I according to the documentation, in order to get the current active video user info you should use the following class: MobileRTCMeetingUserInfo.

Check the doc for the video status class MobileRTCVideoStatus: https://marketplacefront.zoom.us/sdk/meeting/ios/interface_mobile_r_t_c_video_status.html

and you will see that is related with the MobileRTCMeetingUserInfo:
https://marketplacefront.zoom.us/sdk/meeting/ios/interface_mobile_r_t_c_meeting_user_info.html

On that class you will find info of the current user.

Hope you can figure out your problem!
Regards!
Gastón Montes.